# HTTP.GET isn't working

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to load a image from a HTTP.GET into my application. I'm unsure why the picture isn't loading.

Here is my code:

Html:

```
<ion-view view-title="Gallery" align-title="center" ng-controller="photoCtrl">

<ion-content class="center" ng-init="getImages()">


    <div class="item item-divider">
      <i class="ion-images"></i> Under6/7/8/9s Photos
    </div>
    <a class="item item-list-detail">
      <ion-scroll direction="x">
        <img on-hold="onHold()" ng-repeat="image in images" ng-src="images" ng-click="showImages($index)" class="image-list-thumb" />
      </ion-scroll>
    </a>


</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Javascript:

```
.controller("photoCtrl", function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.data = [];

    $scope.getImages = function() {
        $http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/1jovy')
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.data = data;
            })
    }

});
```

Comment: If you add error handling, what occurs? Also is the backend URL you hit setup for allowing GET?

Comment: How do i add an error handler? Yep, the url is allowed Get. I have done it before on myjson through this application.

Comment: `.success(function(data) {...}).error(function(error) {console.log(error)});`

Comment: okay, i will do that now.

Comment: shouldn't use ng-init for this purpose .... in fact no need for `getImages` , just make the request

Comment: @charlietfl, what is a good use for `ng-init`?  Or, is it always bad practice?

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah explained in the docs

Comment: @charlietfl, it's actually very well explained.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors in the console log and i have removed the ng-init part but still cannot receive the image

Comment: no controller defined in your routing

Comment: @charliefl  what do you mean?

Comment: `ng-repeat="data in data"` may not be the best thing either

Comment: read how routing works with controllers in docs

Comment: @charlietfl i have defined my controller. "ng-controller="photoCtrl""   ??? Do you mean defining it in my app.js ?

Comment: I don't see any `ng-controller` in demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your `photoCtrl` [controller to your view](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController)

I saw  `ng-repeat="data in data"`, here item and collection is having same name, which is not a good practice....

If I am rewiting this as `ng-repeat="img in data"` then your ng-src will be like

```
ng-src="{{img}}"
```

updated [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJBMpj)

Comment: Thank you. If i wanted to add an array in my json file how would i reference it in the HTML??

Comment: Kinda, something like this. http://paste.ofcode.org/u5MLDGaaWkq4fdSeaPvC5Y   and then how would i reference that image? staff.img?

Comment: here you can set `staff` as your collection -- [link](http://paste.ofcode.org/6nsVFvKniy5PLJdpgV5QeG)